# First-order system of linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $A(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1&-\frac{1}{x}\\1+x&-1\end{bmatrix}$ who's defined in $I=(0,∞)$ .

I need to find $A,B,C,D$ that make  $y_1(x)= \begin{bmatrix}A+Bx\\C+Dx\end{bmatrix}$ and find the general solution to the ODE - $y'(x) = A(x)y(x)$.

I started by finding the characteristic polynomial of $A(x)$ and found that the eigenvalues are $\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}i , -\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}i$.

I tried to do a find an eigenvectors and compare the eigenvectors that gave me 2 solutions to $y_1(x)= \begin{bmatrix}A+Bx\\C+Dx\end{bmatrix}$ to find $A,B,C,D$ but it doesn't solve that.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A,B,C,D$ that make  $y_1(x)= \begin{bmatrix}A+Bx\\C+Dx\end{bmatrix}$"? Obviously, such a $y_1$ is a solution iff $B=C=A-D=0$.

Comment: $y_1(x)$ is the solution to the ODE. It can't be $B=C=A=D=0$ because that will mean $y(x)=0$ is a solution and were talking about (0,∞)  , no?

Comment: The interval $I$ you specified is with regards to $x$, right? So $y(x)=0$ is a solution. Please clarify what exactly you want to know. Are you looking for solutions of the given form or general solutions?

Comment: Moreover, I did not write $A=D=0$ but $A-D=0.$ Please give it a try: plug your $y_1$ into the ODE and rediscover the result in my 1st comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is not very clear but seems to contain two questions:

- For which constants $A,B,C,D$ is $y_1(x)= \begin{bmatrix}A+Bx\\C+Dx\end{bmatrix}$ a solution of $y'=Ay?$
  The answer, $B=C=A-D=0,$ results from an obvious calculation which I leave to you.
- What is the general solution of $y'=Ay?$
  Let $y=\begin{bmatrix}f\\g\end{bmatrix}.$ Then, $$\begin{align}y'=Ay&\iff f'=f-\frac gx,\quad g'=(1+x)f-g
  \\&\iff f'=f-\frac gx,\quad g'=f+xf'
  \\&\iff xf-g=a\in\Bbb R,\quad f'=\frac ax
  \\&\iff y(x)=\begin{bmatrix}a\ln x+b\\x(a\ln x+b)-a\end{bmatrix}.
  \end{align}$$
  Note that for $a=0$, we recover the solutions $y_1$ of the first question.